# Does malloc make string constants?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

First of all, forgive me if this is a naive question; I'm just a beginner trying to learn.

I am aware that :

```
  char* a = "CD";
```

Stores the string in **read-only memory**; so any changes to the strings are not possible. (constant)

But I did know that this was the case when using malloc too;

```
char* a = malloc(3*sizeof(char)) ;

a = "CD" ; 
a[0] = 'S' ; // even regular a = "MR"; does not work
```

I'm so confused I thought this is stored in the **heap**...

Why can't I modify the string?

Comment: Please excuse the spelling mistakes

Comment: C and C++ are different, choose one and [edit]. I'm guessing you are asking C.

Comment: Sorry about that, just did.

Comment: You're throwing away the memory you've `malloc`ed and pointing the pointer back at a read-only literal.

Comment: Off-topic: It's a good idea always to assign literals to `char const*` pointers – it helps avoiding UB due to modifying immutable memory via these pointers. Literals only are non-const for compatibility reasons (to avoid breaking existing code), as `const` did not exist when they were invented...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a = "CD";` does exactly the same thing as `char* a = "CD";`: it stores the address of `"CD"` into `a`. The value returned by the call to `malloc` is overwritten, and the allocated memory is leaked.

The right way to do this is to **copy** the string:

```
strcpy(a, "CD");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing pointer and allocation:

- `char*` is a pointer to some char in some place in our memory (it may or may not be the heap)
- constant memory such a string (`"CD"`)
- dynamic allocation in the heap.

While the pointer may point to either constant or heap, you may do the same operation (eg: in your example, assign 0 with 'S'). This does not mean it will always work at run time: their may be some protection against this.

For worse example:

```
char* a = "CD";
char* b = "ZZ";
strcpy(a, "EFGHAAAAAAAAAAAA"); // may fail with Segmentation fault
printf("a: %3s, b: %3s\n", a, b); // may not work
```

Using *gcc (Gentoo 7.3.0-r3 p1.4) 7.3.0*, and running the program, it resulted in *Segmentation fault* right at `strcpy`.

You may use `strcpy` only in allocated memory:

```
char* a = malloc(3*sizeof(char)) ;
strcpy(a, "EFGHAAAAAAAAAAAA"); // may fail with Segmentation fault
printf("a: '%s'\n", a); // print a: 'EFGHAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

Doing so, you've gone out of bounds: the memory pointed by a can store up to 3 characters, the latter being the `\0`.

In that case, you should (always?) use `strncpy` instead:

```
char* a = malloc(3*sizeof(char));
strncpy(a, "EFGHAAAAAAAAAAAA", 3 );
a[2] = 0;
```

Beside, you should probably never use `char*` with constant string but `const char*` (the compiler may already warning you about that, if not use `-Wall`):

```
const char* a = "CD" ; 
a[0] = 'S' ; // should not compile
```

Comment: `constant memory such a string ("CD")` is wrong. It is not const memory location. For example on harvard architecture procesoors like AVRs the string will be eventually located in the SRAM

Comment: You may be right on that (I did C a long time ago and only remember from my inconsistent memory), but is that not a but too complicated for beginners?

Comment: `strcpy` may be used on more than allocatef memory. It can generally be used an automatic, static, and other storage.

Answer (score 0):

No you just assign the pointer with address of the string literal and previously stored address of the malloced memory is lost.

Comment: Sident DV-ter - what is wrong in my answer? Or maybe just it is moon phase

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware that :
>
> ```
> char* a = "CD";
> ```
>
> Stores the string in read-only memory; so any changes to the strings are not possible. (constant)

Depends on how you see it. The C standard does not enforce string literals to end up in read only memory. Actually, the C standard does not even require the system to have a read only memory. However, if you attempt to modify a string literal, the behavior is undefined.

Quote from C11 standard:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7